# GzipReader with Range header in http.client doesn't work

Tags: go, gzip

I want to read gzip compressed file from blob storage. I know an URL of storage, offset and length on needed file. So the most simple way to download the file id to use http.client & gzip.Reader

My code is

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2021-10/segments/1614178385529.97/warc/CC-MAIN-20210308205020-20210308235020-00200.warc.gz", nil)
    req.Header.Add("Range", "bytes=842089698-842207846")

    var client http.Client
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    // for key, value := range resp.Header {
    //  fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", key, value)
    // }
    // fmt.Printf("length: %v\n", resp.ContentLength)

    option := 2

    if option == 1 {
        // --- Option 1 ---- 
        reader, _ := gzip.NewReader(resp.Body)
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(0)
        }

        fmt.Println(string(body))
    } else {
        //--- Option 2 ----
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        gr, _ := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(body))
        body, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(gr)

        fmt.Println(string(body))
    }

}
```

If I set option variable to 2 - everything works fine, but if use option #1 programm ends with a error "unexpected EOF". Why does it happen?

Comment: Does `ioutil.ReadAll(gr)` in option #2 return an error?

Comment: option 2 - works fine, I have an issue with option #1

Comment: The difference between the options is that option 1 checks the gzip read error and exits. Option 2 ignores the gzip read error and continues on.

Comment: In both cases, the gzip reader expects more data than provided. It looks like the  document is truncated.